# MVC RadioButtonFor default checked when enum but not for int in viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Noticed a new thing today while trying to solve a problem that I have.

ViewModel:

```
[Required]
public PaymentOption PaymentOption { get; set; }
```

Enum:

```
public enum PaymentOption
{
    CreditCard,
    Invoice
}
```

View:

```
<div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PaymentOption, PaymentOption.CreditCard, new Dictionary<string, object> {{ "id" , "cc" }}) Credit Card
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PaymentOption, PaymentOption.Invoice, new Dictionary<string, object> {{ "id" , "in" }}) Invoice
</div>
```

If I now changed the `PaymentOption` property to an `int` none of the radiobuttons are checked by default when rendering the view.

```
public int PaymentOption { get; set; }
```

If the `PaymentOption` property is an `PaymentOption` enum one of the radiobuttons are checked by default and in the html source the input radio has `checked=checked`.

```
public PaymentOption PaymentOption { get; set; }
```

Why this behavior? Shouldn't it be the same for both `int` and `enum` for the `PaymentOption` property?

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: Yep, sorry, I know the difference.. probably clicked post question too quick!